# set equalities proofs

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I'm teaching my self topology with the aid of a book, the problem i'm on ask to prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $B$ be a subset of $X$. Prove the following set equalities.
> (a) $\overline{X \setminus B} = X \setminus $Int $B $
> (b) Int($X \setminus B $)= $X \setminus  \overline{B} $

I would to know if everything below is correct.

To prove this I'm going to use the following as givens ($S$ is a topoligical space, $U$ and $V$ are subsets of $X$ ):

(I): Int $U = U \setminus \partial U$; "the inside of a set is the whole set minus the border."

(II): $U\setminus V= U \cap (S\setminus V)$; "two ways to say, only U"

(III): $S\setminus (S\setminus U)=U$;"double negative"

(IV):$\partial U = \partial(S\setminus U)$; "a set and its complement have the same border"

(V): $\overline{U} = U \cup \partial U$; "closure is the union of a set and its border"

> (a) $\overline{X \setminus B} = X \setminus $Int $B $

I'm going to start on the right side and and transform it to the left side:

$X \setminus $Int $B $

$X \setminus (B \setminus \partial B)$ ; (I)

$X \setminus (B \cap (X\setminus \partial B))$ ; (II)

$(X \setminus B) \cup (X \setminus  (X\setminus \partial B))$ ; (De Morgan's law)

$(X \setminus B) \cup  \partial B$ ; (III)

$(X \setminus B) \cup  \partial (X\setminus B)$ ; (IV)

$\overline{X \setminus B}$; (V)

> (b) Int($X \setminus B $)= $X \setminus  \overline{B} $

I'm going to start on the right side and and transform it to the left side:

$X \setminus  \overline{B} $

$X \setminus  (B \cup \partial B) $ ; (V)

($X \setminus  B) \cap (X \setminus \partial B) $; (De Morgan's law)

($X \setminus  B) \cap (X \setminus \partial (X\setminus B)) $; (IV)

$(X \setminus  B) \setminus  \partial (X \setminus  B) $; (II)

Int($X \setminus B $);(I)

Comment: Looks pretty good albeit a bit mechanically convoluted k which isn't a bad thing as it is a good way to learn).  Was IV) a set and it's complement have the same boarder a given or a theory?  It is true but how do you know it is true.

Comment: This text seems to base all notions on the primitive of boundary, which is in itself a valid, albeit unconventional, choice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "primitive". Are you saying it would be better to prove without using $\partial B$?

Comment: @Michael: Henno means that you’re taking boundary as the basic notion and expressing closure and interior in terms of it. The most common approach takes closure as the basic notion, expresses $\operatorname{int}A$ in terms of closure as $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$, and expresses boundary either directly in terms of closure ($\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$) or in terms of closure and interior ($\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}A$).